# Emmet is not working with a react in vs code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

Emmet is not working with js files in vscode,

For example in components/Navbar.js if i type div.container, i don't get emmet

i have already added this code and extension is installed:

{
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
}

Comment: instead of typing div.container, try typing div.container{} or div.container> and then pressing the Emmet shortcut key (usually Tab) to expand the abbreviation. and let me know if this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings then extensions and then emmet include languages and add javascript as the item and javascriptreact as the value.

Comment: this didnt worked